# SQL Server : alter column with fix value

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, alter

I have a table with this column

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD TestColumn AS '1'
```

How do I change it to `2`?

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN TestColumn AS '2'
```

doesn't work.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Removing and adding the column is not an option.

Comment: You can't alter a computed column. You have to `DROP` and `ADD` again

Comment: How likely is it that you're going to want to change this "constant" again in the future? At this point, I'd be asking myself if it truly does belong as a computed column in this table at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in my productive system the constant column is a hashcode computed over serval columns and part of a unique key - that's why I didn't want to remove it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is `constant` column, you should recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable DROP COLUMN TestColumn;
ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD TestColumn AS '2';
```

`ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...` syntax is not allowed with `<computed_column_definition>` - see [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

`ALTER COLUMN` allows only following:

```
ALTER COLUMN column_name   
{   
    [ type_schema_name. ] type_name   
        [ (   
            {   
               precision [ , scale ]   
            }   
        ) ]   
    [ COLLATE collation_name ]   
    [ NULL | NOT NULL ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
alter table TestTable 
add default(2) for TestColumn
```